# How to pipe output from a linux command to a python script?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

We have a python script that accepts the following arguments as example:

```
mypie.py --size=20 --pielist='{"apple":[5],"orange":[7]}' --quantity=10
```

We tried in our test.sh bash shell script:

```
test.sh 20 5 7 10
```

test.sh

```
export SIZE=$1
export APPLE=$2
export ORANGE=$3
export QUANTITY=$4

echo "--size=$SIZE" --pipelist='{\"apple\":[$2],\"orange\":[$3]}\"' --quantity=$4" | tee output.txt
cat output.txt | sudo python mypie.py
```

We got error
ERROR: size is not specified.

but when we cat output.txt, we can see that it is there with size value.

```
--size=20 --pielist='{"apple":[5],"orange":[7]}' --quantity=10
```

What are we doing wrong ?
Thanks

Comment: Try: `sudo python mypie.py < output.txt`

Comment: hi alfasin, thanks for responding. doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work" what's the output ? How do you read the args in `mypie.py` ?

Comment: hi it says ERROR: size is not specified.

Comment: @alfasin: the problem is that the OP wants to pass the contents of `output.txt` as arguments, not as standard input.

Comment: @tripleee and if you'll run `python mypie.py < output.txt` that's exactly what's going to happen (the content of output.txt will be redirected as input arguments to the python script). For more info - see my answer below.

Comment: Absent the changes to the Python script suggested in your answer, this *does not* solve the OP's problem.

Comment: @tripleee what do you mean by "absent the changes"?

Comment: @alfasin: Please see [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58854/alfasin)

Comment: @tripleee got it: command-line arguments != standard input. Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 3):

This would do -

`cat output.txt | sudo xargs python mypie.py`

Comment: Sorry, user abc is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/xargs

Comment: The `cat` is useless, though.  `sudo xargs python mypie.py <output.txt`

Comment: If you don't have `sudo` privileges to run `xargs`, maybe try `xargs sudo python mypie.py <output.txt` instead.

Comment: Exactly what @tripleee said would work. Check with this and get back.

Answer (score 3):

Using the pipe redirects the content to stdin of the program - not the command line.
You could consider building up an args variable - then passing that to both the output.txt, and your python script.
For example:

```
export SIZE=$1
export APPLE=$2
export ORANGE=$3
export QUANTITY=$4

export ARGS="--size=$SIZE" --pipelist='{\"apple\":[$2],\"orange\":[$3]}\"' --quantity=$4"

echo $ARGS | tee output.txt
sudo python mypie.py $ARGS
```

Comment: Hi thanks for responding - we got error ERROR: 'str' object has no attribute 'has_key'

Comment: Potentially that's because the pipelist wasn't correctly escaped .. i.e you need to escape the script & the command line - insert additional \'s. export ARGS="--size=$SIZE" --pipelist='{\\"apple\\":[$2],\\"orange\\":[$3]}\\"' --quantity=$4"

Comment: Is it really, really, *really* necessary to have the parameters in a variable, though?  Simply hard-coding the arguments makes the code simpler, more readable, and more maintainable.  See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: `tee` thats new for me. That simplies a lot of my prev code's. Thanks for `tee`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use command substitution to directly place the output of command as the arguments to your python program.

```
python mypie.py `cat output.txt`
```

or

```
python mypie.py $(cat output.txt)
```

Comment: Hi Dunes thanks for responding…It says ERROR: 'str' object has no attribute 'has_key'. Is our escaping single quotes correct - output.txt shows correct argument list

Comment: Python does not automatically evaluate expression on the command line, it just passes the raw string. To turn the string into a `dict` you need to use `eval`, which has security implications, or the more secure `loads` in the `json` module.

Answer (score 1):

The simple and obvious solution is to change `test.sh` so that it passes the parameters correctly.

```
#!/bin/sh
set -x  # if you want to see the script's parameters
sudo python mypie.py --size="$1" \
            --pipelist="{'apple':[$2],'orange':[$3]}" --quantity="$4"
```

Passing the arguments as standard input (which is what a pipe does) is simply not how it is usually done, nor a particularly suitable model for this particular type of interaction.

Comment: I switched to single quotes around the dictionary keys in `pipelist` for legibility reasons.  If they absolutely have to be double quotes, you need to backslash-escape them.